# POST request MyWebKit

Tags: python, python-requests

I have to create POST request with these details but I cannot do it because lack of experience. I have some knowledge and experience in making simple POST and GET requests in Python.

#### Request Example

There is some info about this request that I want to create from that website.
[image]
[image]

#### Code

I have tried to do something like that, but connected session as well.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.dream-singles.com/members/messaging/compose/6658034'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP'}
data = '''------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[draftId]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[replyId]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[type]"

plain_message
------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[buttonClicked]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[plainMessage]"

How are you dear?
------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[htmlMessage]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[galleryId]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[video]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[submit2]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[selectedPhoto]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[saveIntro]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[videoReply]"

1
------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_compose[intro]"


------WebKitFormBoundarym0umZeRAE104X2uP--'''

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: What errors do you get (full console output, including traceback) ? What is your question?
Please avoid images, when you can post text to let us copy/paste-reproduce!

Comment: I do not have any error! I just want to ask a question. How can I even create request POST with this data from the website